# R dataframe permutation function

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function in R that takes a data frame as input and applies a series of steps to every unique pair of rows.

For example, lets say we have data frame with rows A through E. When I put this data frame into the function, I want it to multiply: A x B, A x C, A x D, A x  E, B x C, B x D, B x E, C x D, C x E, and D x E, and then add all of these together. This function would need to handle any number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
  x1<-1:5 #assuming rows A-E of a given data frame `df1` contains the numeric vector x1 
  sum(t(combn(x1,2))[,1]*t(combn(x1,2))[,2])
[1] 85
```

Comment: This looks like it is operating on a vector, not on a data frame as requested by the OP.

Comment: Thanks josilber.I focused only on the numeric vector of a dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're asking to multiply all unique pairs of the rows together, summing their products (therefore the result should be a vector of length equal to the number of columns in the data frame).

I would approach this with the following procedure:

1. Determine all pairs of rows with the `combn` function
2. Compute matrices `mat1` and `mat2`, where `mat1` has the rows from the first element in each pair from Step 1 and `mat2` has the rows from the second element in each pair.
3. Return the column sums of the element-wise product.

You could do these steps pretty simply in R:

```
# Sample data
(X <- matrix(1:6, ncol=2))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    4
# [2,]    2    5
# [3,]    3    6

# Compute the combinations:
(pairs <- combn(nrow(X), 2))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    2
# [2,]    2    3    3
colSums(X[pairs[1,],] * X[pairs[2,],])
# [1] 11 74
```

The first value is `1*2 + 1*3 + 2*3 = 2+3+6 = 11`, and the second value is `4*5 + 4*6 + 5*6 = 20+24+30 = 74`.